# Как передать вводимое в input число в css свойство?

Tags: jquery, input

Есть 2 `input'а`. Первый - *ширина*, второй - *высота*. Также на странице имеется `div`.

**Задача:**
При вводе значений в каждый из `input'ов`,
должно применяться значение к `css` свойству `div'а` - Ширина к `width`, Высота к `height`, и его отображение на странице должно меняться в соответствии с заданными `css` свойствами.

Гуглил, читал статьи, примерно понимаю что все должно крутится вокруг `jQuery` и события `input` и привязке вводимых в него значений к `css` свойствам `div'a`  `width` и `height`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз примерно понимаете, то посмотрите это решение:

```
/*HTML*/
<label>Ширина</label>
<input data-metric=width type=text>
<label>Высота</label>
<input data-metric=height type=text>

<div></div>

/*CSS*/
div {
  background-color:#ccc;
  margin-top:20px
}

/*JS + JQUERY*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[data-metric]').on('keyup', function() {
    if (isNaN($(this).val())) return false;
    $('div').css($(this).data('metric'),$(this).val()+'px');
  })
})
```

Рабочий пример здесь http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVrwGd

Comment: Плохой пример. Событие вешается на все подряд инпуты, используется атрибут ID, причём с довольно легко пересекающимися названиями, ну и в завершение - нет проверки, что введённые данные это число.

Comment: Проверку добавил. То что события вешаются на все инпуты в этом примере это отлично, так как их всего два. В реальном проекте конечно нужен более уникальный селектор. Название атрибута можно легко заменить, например на data

Comment: Да просто судя по уровню вопроса вполне может быть копипаст, и как результат, сломанные формы. :)  Я то понимаю, что пример абстрактный.

Comment: Сломанные формы в результате копипасты могут заставить человека более глубоко изучить вопрос))

Comment: изменил селекторы на более подходящие

Comment: Возможно вы правы )

Comment: Большое спасибо за решение @DmitryOnGamer @SlyDeath, хочется в том то и дело , что не просто копипастнуть а еще и разобраться, буду плотнее изучать `jQery` , спасибо еще раз на наставление в нужную сторону)

Answer (score -1):

```
var $target_div = $('.div'); // Див где будет меняться CSS


$('.width').keyup(function() { // Input ширины
  var width = parseInt($(this).val());
  if (!isNaN(width)) { // Если введённые данные число, то задаём ширину
    $target_div.css('width', width);
  }
});

$('.height').keyup(function() { // Input высоты
  var height = parseInt($(this).val());
  if (!isNaN(height)) { // Если введённые данные число, то задаём высоту
    $target_div.css('height', height);
  }
});
```

Comment: _$('.div'); // Див где будет меняться CSS_ тогда уж дивы :-) по классу же выбираете

Comment: Зачем все дивы? Нужно же менять у конкретного.

Comment: ну вы же делаете выборку **по классу** - следовательно он все дивы с этим классом и вернет

Comment: @Grundy не обязательно класс должен быть у кучи элементов. ;)

Comment: Ага, но если он все-таки будет у кучи - то этот селектор выберет всех.

Comment: @Grundy когда хрен во лбу - медицина бессильна. :) Если вы не контролируете свою вёрстку, то это не значит, что такое положение дел у всех.

Comment: Верстка может получаться разными путями, в том числе и со стороннего сервиса, поэтому завязываться на то, что с классом будет только один элемент - не правильно. В данном случае лучше использовать выборку по id, так как в ее результате всегда вернется максимум _один_ объект

Comment: @Grundy а если сторонний сервис или "кто-то" введёт такой же ID выше вашего? :) А что, если ресайзить нужно не один DIV? ID очень опасны как раз тем, что действие произведётся только с одним из них. Посмотрите на ту же философию БЭМ, там ID используют в сугубо крайних случаях. :) Любой элемент должен быть ре-юзабельным. Иначе в вёрстке будет куча нарушений DRY.

Comment: Ну так и начальная претензия была именно к подписи :-) если выбирается по классу - может быть несколько, следовательно должно быть: _Дивы где будет меняться CSS_, если речь идет про _только_ один див: то надо было использовать id

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33513/discussion-between-grundy-and-slydeath).